# Insertar en una tabla solo cuando no exista el registro

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en MySql y en ella quiero ingresar datos desde otra tabla ubicada en una base de datos diferente, los datos se insertan de manera correcta si ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
    INSERT INTO courses_members (course_id, user_id, added, validity, active, suma, fecha_solicitud)
SELECT sc.id AS course_id, sm.id AS user_id, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y/%m/%d') AS added,
'0000-00-00' AS validity, 'Activo' AS active, 'si' AS suma, '0000-00-00' AS fecha_solicitud 
FROM chamilo.course cc 
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.courses sc ON cc.title=sc.name 
INNER JOIN chamilo.skill_rel_user sru ON sru.course_id=cc.id
INNER JOIN chamilo.user cu ON cu.id=sru.user_id 
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members sm ON sm.email=cu.email;
```

Pero al querer validar que se inserten solo si ese registro no existe en la tabla destino no se inserta ningún resultado.

```
    INSERT INTO courses_members (course_id, user_id, added, validity, active, suma, fecha_solicitud)
SELECT sc.id AS course_id, sm.id AS user_id, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y/%m/%d') AS added,
'0000-00-00' AS validity, 'Activo' AS active, 'si' AS suma, '0000-00-00' AS fecha_solicitud 
FROM chamilo.course cc 
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.courses sc ON cc.title=sc.name 
INNER JOIN chamilo.skill_rel_user sru ON sru.course_id=cc.id
INNER JOIN chamilo.user cu ON cu.id=sru.user_id 
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members sm ON sm.email=cu.email
#INNER JOIN chamilo.course_rel_user cre ON cre.c_id=cc.id
WHERE sc.id NOT IN(SELECT course_id FROM sm4rtuniversity.courses_members)
AND sm.id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM sm4rtuniversity.courses_members);
```

La consulta no arroja ningún error pero no se inserta ningún resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me imagino que la llave de tu tabla es la combinación de las columnas `course_id, user_id`. Esto significa la combinación de ambos valores en una fila no se puede repetir.

Lo que tú estás filtrando, en cambio, es que el curso no exista antes y que el usuario no exista antes. Entonces, por ejemplo, basta con que tu tabla tenga un usuario para cada curso para que tu filtro no permita insertar ninguna otra fila.

Lo que tienes que hacer es ver que la combinación de esas filas no exista antes:

```
INSERT INTO courses_members (course_id, user_id, added, validity, active, suma, fecha_solicitud)
SELECT  sc.id AS course_id, 
        sm.id AS user_id, 
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y/%m/%d') AS added,
        '0000-00-00' AS validity, 
        'Activo' AS active, 
        'si' AS suma, 
        '0000-00-00' AS fecha_solicitud 
FROM chamilo.course cc 
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.courses sc 
    ON cc.title=sc.name 
INNER JOIN chamilo.skill_rel_user sru 
    ON sru.course_id=cc.id
INNER JOIN chamilo.user cu 
    ON cu.id=sru.user_id 
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members sm 
    ON sm.email=cu.email
INNER JOIN chamilo.course_rel_user cre 
    ON cre.c_id=cc.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sm4rtuniversity.courses_members
                 WHERE course_id = sc.id
                 AND user_id = sm.id)
;
```

Comment: Excelente funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias. Solo una pequeña duda y a lo mejor es un poco absurda pero, ¿porque "SELECT 1"?

Comment: @GuillermoRicardoSpindolaBri Podrías usar `SELECT *`, `SELECT AlgunaColumna`, `SELECT NULL`, `SELECT 2`...en fin, cualquier `SELECT`. Lo único que verifica es que haya algún resultado, y yo uso `SELECT 1` para dejar explícito a algún otro desarrollador que lo único que me interesa es la existencia de una fila, no los datos que contiene